# Can user1's process kill user2's process?

Tags: linux, users, root, signals, non-root-user

Linux kernel supports the traditional concept of a Unix user.

Every user-space process has a user *owner*.

Every user-name has corresponding *userid* in kernel. Kernel does not know  *user-name*.

*Groups* are sets of users. The primary purpose of groups is to allow a user to share file access to other users in a group.

If non-root users, `user1` & `user2`, **are not** in same user group(say `developer`), then, `user1` **cannot modify** the files/directories owned by `user2`.

If non-root users `user1` & `user2` **are** in same user group(say `developer`), then, `user1` **can modify** the files/directories owned by `user2`.

---

**Question**

If `user1` & `user2` are in same group, then,

Does kernel allow `user1`'s process to send any signal(say `SIGKILL` with `kill` command) to a process owned by `user2`?

Comment: If the two users are in the same group, they still can't modify each other's files, unless the files are writable by the group.

Comment: @Kusalananda A non group user cannot atleast(read) the file of other user. A group user can access the file based on group permissions. Is that correct?

Comment: Any user can access (read, write) any other file based on the permissions on the file. If a file is group readable, then the group can read it. If it's readable by "others", then anyone can read it. Likewise for writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIX says:

> For a process to have permission to send a signal to a process
>   designated by pid, unless the sending process has appropriate
>   privileges, the real or effective user ID of the sending process shall
>   match the real or saved set-user-ID of the receiving process.

so no. The sending process needs to be privileged (root) or the UIDs must match.

Comment: When it says, `For a process` in your answer, if I run `kill <pid>` command on command prompt, is it a shell process sending kill signal to some pid?

Comment: Yes -- kill is a builtin in common shells. (You can also explictly run /bin/kill in which case a new process will be spawned for it.)

Comment: So, any non-root user process1 can send signal to only same non-root user process2. Is that correct?

Comment: @overexchange root processes can kill any other process. Regular processes can only kill another process if the other process runs under the same user.

Comment: Assuming both users in same group, user1 can modify files/directories owned by user2, but user1's process cannot send signal to a process owned by user2. Tricky

Comment: For any reason, can `root` be part of a group? Or Is it always a  sole user with extra privileges?

Comment: @overexchange This is a different question and you should post it as such. :-) There can be only one root user because there can be only one user with UID 0, and this is defined as root by the kernel. But then you have capabilities. Any process with capability CAP_KILL can signal everybody else.

Comment: @PSkocik So, Can I say *group* concept has nothing to do with enabling one of the users' process to send signals to other users' process in that group? *group* concept is introduced only for files/directories but not processes

Comment: @overexchange Group user ids of processes have no effect on their killability. That's what the standard says, IMO, and also how my Linux system behaves.